# Подскажите бесплатные API ресурсы на подобие {JSON} Placeholder API для тренировки авторизации(login/logout)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Для тренировки при изучении REACTа, нужно какое-то API чтоб потренироваться делать авторизацию, или подскажите где можно потренироваться

Answer (score 0):

Можно поискать на GitHub [react real world application](https://github.com/search?q=react+real+world+application). В начале списка есть [фронтенд на React](https://github.com/gothinkster/react-redux-realworld-example-app), c [API](https://conduit.productionready.io/api/). Я пробовал разбирать это приложение. Там есть достаточно, чтобы потренироваться не только с авторизацией.